# Dynamic Programming (max sum)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a sequence of *n* real numbers *A(1) ... A(n)*, determine a contiguous sub sequence *A(i) ... A(j)* for which the sum of elements in the sub sequence is maximized.

The solution is:

```
M(j) = max sum over all windows ending in j

M(j) = max{M(j-1) +A[j], A[j]}
```

Could someone please explain how this works for the following sub sequence: 
`1, 5, -10, 5`. Because between the first `5` and `-10` the recurrence selects between a sum of `-4 (M(j-1) +A[j])` or `-10 (M(j-1) +A[j])`. But, the best sum is `6`.

So shouldn't the recurrence be:

```
M(j) = max{M(j-1) +A[j], A[j], M(j-1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said `M[j] = maximum sum over all windows ending at j`.
so after computing `M[j]` for all `j` between `0` and `n - 1`. You output the maximum of them.
Here is a sample code in C++.

```
int findMax(int a[], int n){
    int * M = new int[n];
    M[0] = a[0];
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
        M[i] = max(M[i-1] + a[i], a[i]);
    int ans = M[0];
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
        ans = max(ans, M[i]);

    return ans;
}
```

for your sequence `{1, 5, -10, 5}`. `M = {1, 6, -4, 5}` and the answer is the maximum value in `M` which is 6.